# Setting bluetooth passcode on a HP Notebook

Tags: passwords, bluetooth

I've got a HP Compaq nx6320 & I just installed the HP bluetooth drivers (WinXP) and I'm trying to pair my Samsung Windows Mobile phone with it, but when I do, the phone asks me to enter the passcode for the computer, but I never set one in the install process & I've got no idea how to set it now.
Does anyone know where this option is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just `1234`. Many bluetooth devices either have that as their default. It is also possible that it is asking you to *create* a PIN.

Comment: Yup, it wanted me to confirm the pin I'd already entered on the phone. Me Fail